# How to reuse a window in another frame for display-buffer

Tags: frames, display-buffer-alist, display-buffer

I like to have the *Help* buffer in a some frame (with some other windows) and I try to reuse this window in this frame even when I am in another frame and issue a help command.

I tried setting

```el
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(("\\*Help\\*" display-buffer-reuse-window)))
```

but this seem to reuse the window only when it is in the same frame.

How can I tell the display-buffer system to reuse a window in *any* (visisble) frame?

Answer (score 1):

> reuse a window in another frame

The key to achieving this lies in using an *action alist* entry `reusable-frames`. For instance, setting its value to `0` with `(reusable-frames . 0)` enables searching for a reusable window on all visible or iconified frames.

The corresponding part of a configuration could then look as shown below (`setopt` is available since *Emacs 29.1*).

```el
(setopt
 'display-buffer-alist
 '(("\\*Help\\*"
    (display-buffer-reuse-window
     display-buffer-in-previous-window
     display-buffer-use-some-frame
     display-buffer-pop-up-frame)
    (reusable-frames . visible))))
```

For more insight on how to manage Emacs windows, see [Demystifying Emacs’s Window Manager](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/demystifying-emacs-window-manager).

And documentation, of course. In particular, I find the following pages to be the most helpful:

- [`(info "(emacs) Window Choice")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html)
- [`(info "(elisp) The Zen of Buffer Display")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Zen-of-Buffer-Display.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation for the function you're using.

Refer to all of the details regarding frames:

```
display-buffer-reuse-window is a byte-compiled Lisp function in
`window.el'.

(display-buffer-reuse-window BUFFER ALIST)

Return a window that is already displaying BUFFER.
Preferably use a window on the selected frame if such a window
exists.  Return nil if no usable window is found.

ALIST is an association list of action symbols and values.  See
Info node `(elisp) Buffer Display Action Alists' for details of
such alists.

If ALIST has a non-nil `inhibit-same-window' entry, the selected
window is not eligible for reuse.

If ALIST contains a `reusable-frames' entry, its value determines
which frames to search for a reusable window:
  nil -- the selected frame (actually the last non-minibuffer frame)
  A frame   -- just that frame
  `visible' -- all visible frames
  0   -- all frames on the current terminal
  t   -- all frames.

If ALIST contains no `reusable-frames' entry, search just the
selected frame if `display-buffer-reuse-frames' and
`pop-up-frames' are both nil; search all frames on the current
terminal if either of those variables is non-nil.

If ALIST has a non-nil `inhibit-switch-frame' entry, then in the
event that a window on another frame is chosen, avoid raising
that frame.

This is an action function for buffer display, see Info
node `(elisp) Buffer Display Action Functions'.  It should be
called only by `display-buffer' or a function directly or
indirectly called by the latter.
```

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know, that  `display-buffer-reuse-window` is a normal function. But how can I give it as a property in `display-buffer-alist` the additional parameter so that it finds the window in other frames as well?

Comment: Follow the documented manual links, and see the adjacent node `(elisp)The Zen of Buffer Display` for many examples.